# Conversation flow works in 'Try it out' but skips child node in app

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson, watson-conversation

I am making an app that predicts clothes the user is wearing. It uses the Visual Recognition tool, too, and for Conversation and VR to be communicating, I attach the intent 'suggestClothing' or 'clothResult' to the cloth items it found. I use an entity for Conversation to recognize the cloth items and respond accordingly.

The flow should be as follows:

**User:** how do I look?
-classifies clothes-
**App to conversation:** clothSuggest blackJacket
**Conversation to user:** "You picked the black jacket! Try out the green shirt with this outfit and show me how you look."
-classifies clothes-
**App to conversation:** clothResult blackJacket greenShirt
**Conversation to user:** "You look great in that outfit!"

All nodes have multiple responses as all clothes are in pairs. Either the user is wearing one or the other, and Conversation will then always suggest it's match.

[Conversation flow looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VHp9.png)

I also attempted this. Here sq123 is suggestClothing (first intent) and cq123 is clothResult:

[This works fine in 'Try it out', too, but in the app, it immediately exits the branch on 'clothResult item1 item2' and matches with other conditions in the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vZUG.png) 
What's the best way to optimize my flow to make it work in the app?

Answer (score 0):

A typical reason why it works in "Try it out" and not in the app is that the context object is not returned properly.

When the app invokes the [message method of the Watson Assistant API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl#message-api), a context object is passed. The calls are stateless and everything needed for Watson Assistant to continue a dialog is included in the context object. Thus, when your app retrieves the results from the `message API`, it needs to save the context and pass it back to Watson Assistant the next time the message method is invoked again (for that session and user).

Comment: It works. The problem was, indeed, the context object. Thank you.